# Use method from another class on ArrayList with foreach loop?

Tags: java

```
public void verschuif1(){
    for(Object x : puntenLijst){
        x.verschuif2(3, 3);
    }
}
```

puntenLijst is an ArrayList of object instances from another class.
Now I tried to do something with a foreach loop that loops through all objects in the ArrayList and uses the method verschuif2() (from an other class) on it.

But it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe the compiler doesn't understand Dutch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to cast your objects first:

```
for (Object x : puntenLijst){
    ((MyObject)x).verschuif2(3, 3);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use generics in your `ArrayList`. So for an `ArrayList` like this:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> puntenLijst
```

You could avoid casting altogether:

```
for (MyObject x : puntenLijst){
   x.verschuif2(3, 3);
}
```

Related: [Why use Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast before invoking the method

```
((ClassName) x).verschuif2(3, 3);
```

to make it compile.

Better than that is to make your list generic

```
List<ClassName> puntenLijst = new ArrayList<ClassName>();
```

then you won't need to cast (which is considered type unsafe). Then you would loop  as follows

```
for (ClassName x : puntenLijst){ 
    x.verschuif2(3, 3); // no casting required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loop operates on Object references. If your method isnt declared in Object your code has no way of knowing that the method call is valid.

Wht you need is for puntjenblist to be declared similarly to this:

Collection where {type} is some class that declares the versschuif2 method.

Then in your for loop you can reference objects via {type} in order to call that method.

That way the for loop know that every object in the collection has that method that can be called.